# AVPlayer doesnt Play URL Sound Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, avplayer, xcode8

I want to play a mp3 file via AVPlayer in Swift 3 (Xcode 8.0). Its a remote file which is hosted on my localhost. This code was works fine in Swift 2.2 Xcode 7.3.1, and then now in Xcode 8.0 It doesn't work and I really don't know why.
My Code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit
var player = AVPlayer()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let videoURL = URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1/stream/ebXbLfLACGM")

    player = AVPlayer(url:videoURL!)

    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)

    playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)

    player.play()
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to override Transport Security? In recent builds of iOS, only connections with https are allowed by default.

Comment: @ZhangChn Yes. Because I can load a JSON from my local host and Its works. But when I want to play It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some hours challenging with this issue. I restart my localhost webservice and also I restart Xcode,and then It works!! And I really don't know what magic happened!